# Using external javascript files in node.js without using export and require

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't like the whole export/require stuff in node, it takes too long. Let's say I have a file server.js and I want to use functions in whatever.js. in html I just add this to the header:

```
<script src='whatever.js'></script>
```

and then I can just use all the functions of whatever.js in my body's script.

But in node, in the server.js file I'd do:

```
var myobject = require('./whatever.js');
```

but then I need to set it to myobject, and further I need to go to whatever.js and manually decide what functions I want to export. not to mention that typing myobject.someFunction() is alot longer to write than someFunction() and I need to remember what I exposed/didn't expose.

I wanted something where I could just go:

```
require('./whatever.js');
```

and it puts it ALL in global, no bs. like in good old html/javascript. Is there a way to do this in node?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503599/node-js-configure-node-to-load-functions-into-the-global-scope

Comment: not the same question, and horrible answers

Comment: Best answer i ever read on variable scope un nodejs : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433080/7131047

Comment: you could write a script that looks for functions and appends export const to every funciton eg. function foo => export const foo and rewrites the file

Comment: or takes the function name and makes it global eg function foo => global.foo = function

Comment: What you want sounds like a terrible idea. It takes one module to overwrite anything you imported and your code is broken.

Comment: @RodrigoLeite nah I like everything being in global. tough titty if something breaks. i can deal with those problems as they come esp for insignificant tools and testing that I'm doing.

Comment: If you don't care about quality and maintainability, just put everything in one giant javascript file and then you don't even need to load anything. (Being a bit sarcastic in case you can't tell :p )

Comment: one could argue that having to manually decide what to export compromises maintainability cause it takes longer. imagine if you had to do that in html. no thanks.

Comment: Deciding what to import costs much less time than trying to figure out why a random function is breaking on a two thousand line file. There's a reason these practices are considered terrible.

Comment: Good for you, it's still terrible practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

This will do the trick,

```
var fs = require('fs');

eval(fs.readFileSync('whatever.js')+'');
 // here call functions from whatever.js file
```

Comment: lol that is the hackiest crap I've ever seen in my life so will not use it. but that's pretty awesome answer +1.

Answer (score 2):

(I realize this is an old thread but wanted to leave a note here for posterity.)

Here in 2022 there are several approaches for executing code from different files with Node.js:

### ESM: Use [standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-modules) [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules)

At the time of this writing, much of the node ecosystem (i.e. packages on npm) is in the process of transitioning to this paradigm, and there are some associated growing pains (e.g. things like [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#__dirname) are only available in CJS not ESM, though the [workaround is easy](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2907#issuecomment-757446568)).
For most developers, it would be advisable to become comfortable with this standard as it transcends node.js (i.e. is implemented in other runtimes like [Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.20.6/examples/import_export) and web browsers) and has been years in the making.

### CJS: Use the original ["CommonJS" module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules) mechanism, e.g. `require('./some-script.js')`

It should be noted, particularly for the OP, that even though the ["intended" way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) to use CJS modules is to export functions, constants, etc. and import them explicitly, it is possible to define everything in global scope using [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis), though I would not recommend this.

```js
// my-script.js
require('./foo.js');
require('./bar.js');
foo(); // This is foo from <...>foo.js
console.log(`bar = ${bar} (in ${__filename})`); // bar = 123 (in <...>my-script.js)

// foo.js
globalThis.foo = function() {
  console.log(`This is foo from ${__filename}`);
}

// bar.js
globalThis.bar = 123;
```

If you try omitting `globalThis.` you'll find that `foo` and `bar` are no longer defined in the main script because `require` "wraps them" in "module scope."

### Use `eval`

In my experience, there are very few legitimate use cases for [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (see [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)). Nevertheless, the functionality requested in this question is precisely what `eval` provides: "run some code as if it were written right here" and you can feed it from a file, as explained [above by Mehul Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986958/using-external-javascript-files-in-node-js-without-using-export-and-require#answer-45987524)

```js
// include.js 
// Defines a global function that works like C's "#include" preprocessor directive
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
globalThis.include = function(scriptFile) {
  console.warn('!!! EXTREMELY INSECURE !!!');
  eval(readFileSync(scriptFile, 'utf-8'));
};


// main.js
require('./include.js'); // loads global include

// (I sure hope you completely trust these sources)
include('./foo.js');
include('./bar.js');
```

---

**Note:** Something that has contributed to much of my confusion in the past is that there have been competing standards/conventions/APIs that use some of the same identifiers, namely `require`, which [`require.js`](https://requirejs.org/) and other [bundlers](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/) [that](https://www.rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputformat) [support](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/819) [AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition)](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md)
use with different semantics. So for someone building a web application (using AMD for modules in web browsers) with node.js tooling (using CJS for modules locally) it can be frustrating to keep the functions straight, especially if it's an [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) application, which can expose Node.js APIs to scripts running in the renderer (browser). If you find yourself confused why a module is "not found" in a situation like that, check the stack trace to see which `require` is being called (and you may have to wrap/rename them on `globalThis` or something to avoid collisions).

Further reading:

- [JavaScript Modules: A Brief History [2019]](https://objectpartners.com/2019/05/24/javascript-modules-a-brief-history/)
- [How the module system, CommonJS & require works [updated 2022]](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/)
- [What is AMD, CommonJS, and UMD? [2014]](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/)